# How to build installer of some files?

Tags: windows, installer

I have some files on my laptop and I need to build either an `exe` or `msi` installer.

My intention is that when running that installer, it must place one file on to the `C:` disk and another file to the desktop.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Well there are plethora of Package and Deploy installer platforms available. The simplest for your kind of use would be [lzPAck](http://izpack.org/). Its free and open source.

Answer (score 4):

[iexpress](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd346760.aspx) should do the trick - it lets you create a self extracting file thats scriptable and run commands once thats done. Its also part of nearly every version of windows, and has a wizard that walks you through the process.

Answer (score 2):

[NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) is also a great option for you as well.  You can tell it to put anything anywhere, and create whatever shortcuts you want.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to specify and create installers, but it's been a while.